# Are there any compatibility issues with 3D enabled grahics cards and big screen TVs?

Tags: laptop, tv, laptop-display, 3d-vision

I am looking at maybe getting a big screen TV for the sole purpose of gaming and am willing to drop $1k+. Time to bust out the ol' Best Buy cedit card (love the interest rate).  However, I feel that I would be extremely disappointed if I came home with BF3 and then I get no 3D joy from the setup.  From playing the beta, there are some graphics settings that imply the game is 3D capable.  I have one of the ASUS beast laptops, G73 I think?  Thing comes with an Nvidia Geforce GTX460M 1Gb card, and have read up on the specs that the graphics card supports 3D signaling.  However, continued reading would show the laptop monitor did not support 3D projection.  The required frequency must be >= 120hz for 3D to be possible.

**While I give a specific example, I like to open this question to any graphics card and TV make and model that would suport a given laptop hooked to a 3D tv for a 3D experience.**

Comment: I know two things: make sure your video card supports generating 120Hz 3D graphics, and make sure you can hook it up with a HDMI cable.  I recently had an LG 60Hz 3D monitor which used the third-party software *TriDef 3D* to create the 3D, but I retured it when I discovered it only supported *DirectX 9*.